# Accumulation points and bounded open sets

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose $S$ is a bounded open set in the reals and suppose that the least upper bound of $S$ is $7$.  Prove that $7$ is not an element of $S$. Use the definition of accumulation point to prove that $7$ is an accumulation point of *S*.

I answered the first part by saying that because $S$ is an open set, it must have or have a subset with the bounds $(x,7)$ where $x$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}$ because $7$ is the least upper bound. Then we can see that $7$ isn't a part of $S$. Is there a more technical way to prove this?

And I really don't know what to prove for the accumulation point.  I want to say that because $S$ goes from $(x,7)$ that $7$ has to be an accumulation point because it can't be by itself, i.e. $[7]$ so it must be close to something else. Again, is there a more technical way to prove this?

Comment: I think it might be cleaner to attempt a proof by contradiction. Suppose that $7$ is an upper bound of $S$ but that $7$ actually **is** an element of $S$ and try to contradict $S$ being open.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $7$ is an element of $S$. As $S$ is open, there is some $r>0$ such that $(7-r,7+r) \subseteq S$. But then $7 + \frac{r}{2}$ is in $S$ (as it is in the open interval), and so $7$ is not an upper bound of $S$, which is a contradiction.

Now, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $x \in S$ such that $x \in (7 - \varepsilon, 7)$. For if this were not the case, $7 - \varepsilon$ would be a smaller upper bound for $S$ than $7$ (we already know no elements of $S$ are $>7$) and this contradicts $7$ being the *least* upper bound. This shows that $7$ is indeed an accumulation point of $S$.